# DataTable.js - Always return an empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

When I try to access the .DataTable() function its always return null, I have been really struggling with this...
Here is my code : [view jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35v9r9p1/)

**HTML:**

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Name </th>
            <th> Age </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th> Rotem </th>
            <th> 18 </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> Bar </th>
            <th> 13 </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> Shadmot </th>
            <th> 8 </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th> Devora </th>
            <th> 78 </th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<button id="button"> Click me </button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var b = $('#example').dataTable();

     $('#button').on('click', function() {
        window.alert(b);
     });
 });
```

Thank you very much

Comment: b is not null, but when i need to use b ( b.DataTable() its always return an empty array )

Answer (score 1):

What you got in `b` is the [API](https://datatables.net/manual/api) to the data table library. If you change it to say

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var b = $('#example').DataTable();

     $('#button').on('click', function() {
        b.search("13");
        b.draw();
     }); 
 });
```

you will get the correct result. You really have to read the manuals in these times you can't get away with mere wild guessing as in the old times.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my answer a little bit.  In the button handler, I get the instance of  data table inside the handler. Note that I used capital D to get the instances.  In my example, q returns the data in column form 2x4 array, and s = returns the data in rows form 4x4 array.   Note that I also added the css style sheet and moved the links to the top.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var b = null;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                 b = $('#example').dataTable();

                $('#button').on('click', function () {
                    var q = $('#example').DataTable().columns().data();
                    var s = $('#example').DataTable().rows().data();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
        <body>
            <table id="example" class='display'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Name </th>
                        <th> Age </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Rotem </th>
                        <th> 18 </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Bar </th>
                        <th> 13 </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Shadmot </th>
                        <th> 8 </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Devora </th>
                        <th> 78 </th>
                    </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
            <button id="button"> Click me </button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not so stupid it may appear. I had the same problem, but not because of api misunderstanding. 
This was because, after having initialized a main datatable in my page, I was loading by ajax some partial HTML code, which was including the `<script src="../dataTables.js">` in it. So dataTable plugins was loaded twice in the page. And of course (even it took me a bit of time to understand..), the `$(selector).DataTable().rows()`, or `$(selector).dataTable().api().rows()`, were both returning empty array, while my table was still there and clearly visible...
Removing the duplicate datatable.js script loading solved the issue.